# textarea size getting smaller when width unit is % and working fine when used pixel

Tags: html, css, flexbox, less

Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/dhanu10896/ohb3xayn/11/ 
I have textarea and one instruction below it and i have to show that instruction below the right bottom end of textarea, and also text area is resizable so the instruction should adjust with it when the size of text area increased.

For this I enclosed  textarea and instruction in one div and made it inline block, which will take width of textarea and aligned instruction to right side.

This is working when width is in pixel but when width is in % (percentage) it's not working.

code :

```css
displayCell {
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
}

html form, body form {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #32363a;
    font-family: '72', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}

.displayInlineBlock, .inlineBlock {
    display: inline-block;
}

html textarea, body textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: '72', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    font-weight: 400;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    font-size: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #89919a;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #32363a;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 125ms;
    transition: border-color 125ms;
    height: 36px;
    height: var(--fd-forms-height);
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.displayFlex {
    display: flex;
}
html .textareaInstruction, body .textareaInstruction {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 0px;
    text-align: right !important;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85714rem;
    line-height: 1.33333;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #51555a;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.formElementInstruction {
    color: #666666;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.mr2px {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>

<h2>
to fix
</h2>
  <div class="displayCell clearfix">
    <div class="inlineBlock">
      <textarea name="description" id="description" style="width:100%;height:100px;width:75%;"></textarea>
      <div class="displayFlex">
        <div class="formElementInstruction  textareaInstruction">
          <span class="mr2px" id="text_counter_description">1000</span>left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <h2>
  should look like (also try resizing texarea)
  </h2>
   <div class="displayCell clearfix">
    <div class="inlineBlock">
      <textarea name="description" id="description" 
      style="height:100px;width:500px;"></textarea>
      <div class="displayFlex">
        <div class="formElementInstruction  textareaInstruction">
          <span class="mr2px" id="text_counter_description">1000</span>left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

As on your textarea containing block you applied class `inlineBlock` which has set property `display: inline-block` div will not stratch to the full width and it will take the space only needed by textarea.

Also as you set `style="width:100%;height:100px;width:75%;"` on textarea it will be 75% of it's parent and here parent is the div with class `inlineBlock` so it will be 75% of this div not the 75% of device width.

Set `width` property only one time as the last one will override the first one.

If you don't want to set pixel on those textarea you can fix this by following approach:

```
.displayInlineBlock, .inlineBlock {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 500px;
}

<textarea name="description" id="description" style="width:100%;height:100px"></textarea>
```

Here is the fiddle link to view the working solution http://jsfiddle.net/aditi17/t2sybfr7/257/

Comment: this will not adjust instruction when textarea size is reduced! any other approach to creating such textarea and instruction feature.

Comment: @dhanu10896 Yes on reducing textarea it will not work so best way to acheive this is to set width in pixel.

Comment: i was not able to fix it completely with CSS but I have written one JS function to handle resizing  event of both textarea and instruction, so that instruction will always have same width as textarea.https://jsfiddle.net/dhanu10896/ohb3xayn/52/

Answer (score 0):

give full width (eg:100vw) to the text area.

```css
displayCell {
  padding: 2px 0 3px 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.clearfix {
  display: block;
}

html form, body form {
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #32363a;
    font-family: '72', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;
}
.clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
.displayInlineBlock, .inlineBlock {
    display: inline-block;
}

html textarea, body textarea {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: '72', -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif, Apple Color Emoji, Segoe UI Emoji, Segoe UI Symbol;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    font-weight: 400;
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    font-size: inherit;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    outline: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #89919a;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #32363a;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: border-color 125ms;
    transition: border-color 125ms;
    height: 36px;
    height: var(--fd-forms-height);
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 72px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

.displayFlex {
    display: flex;
}
html .textareaInstruction, body .textareaInstruction {
    flex-grow: 1;
    width: 0px;
    text-align: right !important;
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    font-size: .85714rem;
    line-height: 1.33333;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #51555a;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.formElementInstruction {
    color: #666666;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.mr2px {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<form>

<h2>
to fix
</h2>
  <div class="displayCell clearfix">
    <div class="inlineBlock">
      <textarea name="description" id="description" style="width:90vw;height:100px;"></textarea>
      <div class="displayFlex">
        <div class="formElementInstruction  textareaInstruction">
          <span class="mr2px" id="text_counter_description">1000</span>left</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try resizing textarea the instruction text doesn't move with it!

Comment: Hi gaurav, that's what i said in question it's working with pixel but when used %

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: i have huge code base, in which some texarea's have width in percentage and some in pixel. I don't want to change there percentage so need fix by keeping those percentage as it is.